# dataset particular table binding in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

i have passed a dataset to another page through session,now i want to bind the particular table of dataset with the different gridviews of another page i.e. the page to which i have sent my dataset as session.
In page load of another page i am writing-

```
        if (Session["tt"] != null)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = Session["tt"];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Now i want to assign partcular table of this session to gridview-
pseudocode of something i want is-

```
        if (Session["tt"] != null)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = Session["tt"].Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

now how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the tt object in Session to DataSet and then use it. See below code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var ds = Session["tt"] as System.Data.DataSet;

            if (ds != null)
            {
                gvFiles.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                gvFiles.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps.